# Firebird performance depends on the connected user?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I have a Firebird 2.5 database that performs intensive read / write operations. I have about 15 defined users who have read / write permissions on the data in the database.

Even with a single connection to the database, I notice that if I connect with the SYSDBA user these operations are executed a few times faster than any other user.

Has anyone noticed this behavior? I do not want regular users to connect with SYSDBA to the database to get increased performance.

Comment: I suggest you ask this on the firebird-support mailing list; I'm not aware of such a 'problem', but I can theorize that there might be slightly less overhead for sysdba as some permission checks can be skipped that need to be done for normal users, however I'd expect that difference would be negligible. Avoiding people connecting with sysdba is simple: don't give them the sysdba password of your server.

Comment: there can be very many things, like for example triggers logging all the operations for all the users EXCEPT the sysdba. There should be some database-specific logic. Personally i'd extract all the meta-data into big text file and then look for SYSDBA in it. If not found - then both metadata and data.